# How to change the look of Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I've downloaded the latest version of Orchard (0.5) and I've looked at the initial layout of the site.  Looks good.  But, it only allows me to edit different parts of it and not the actual layout of the page.... or does it?  If so, how do I go about changing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Managing-widgets.ashx) to understand the concept of layers and zones.

Basically, you can customize the zone (a place to put a widget or a place where content goes) layout of a particular page by matching it to a layer (using a rule defined in by the layer). The layer structure allows for inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to grab the 0.8 version when it's available Monday 10/25/2010: we did a lot of work around UI composition for that release, basically rewriting the whole UI layer. We're also writing new documentation for those features that you'll find on http://orchardproject.net shortly.
A theme can override the layout of the whole page or of any shape on it by just providing a new template or shape rendering method.

Comment: I downloaded the 0.8 version and this doesn't suit my needs.  Have moved to Umbraco instead.